# How to store user specific data in Django

Tags: python, django, web

In Django,
How can we store user specific data?

I'm trying to creating a django web app, where user needs to remember the order of random sequence fetched from database.

I have two functions in my views, home and result

I tried to store random sequence generated by home function into a global variable, and use that to validate in results function.

But , I think this can serve only one user at time

What if second user requested for home page and that cause change in global variable, resulting unable to validate first user.

Comment: Why can't you use a local variable?

Comment: Then how I can preserve the order, first generated by home function. Im not sure.

Comment: Sorry, your question was unclear that there were two views. Nevermind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tackle the problem with `Django Session`.

In home view you can set variables by :

```
request.session['varibale_name'] = varibale_value
```

You can access these variables in result view by :

```
request.session['varibale_name']
```

After job done you can also delete the session variable by :

```
del request.session['varibale_name']
```